# Find a series convergent $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum\sqrt{a_n/n}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is part of an exercise 8.22 from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis.  I've looked at things like, $a_n=1/\sqrt n-1/\sqrt{n+1}$, and $a_n=1/\log n^{\log n}$, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That works perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome. Denominator $n\log^p n$ with $1\lt p\le 2$ works. For simplicity I took the far end.