# Convergence of series under specific conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{a_n}{n}}$ converge given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges?

While studying for my real analysis final, I wrote some practice problems, and this one is far harder than anticipated. If I had a radical with a different power in the denominator, I can show this converges or doesn't converge in general. I have tried looking at partial sums and using Minkowski's inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, Chebyshev's sum inequality, and the usual ratio, direct comparison, limit comparison, and root tests. Does anyone know the answer or have any hints?

Comment: Hint : Consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$

Comment: I have tried that. As $ a_n $ converges, we know $ \alpha >1 $, thus $ \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}}{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}} $. As the denominator has a power greater than 1, all series of that form will converge, but this does not answer the question for all convergent $ a_n $.

Comment: More generally, how about $\sum_{n = 1} F(a_n / n)$ for a concave $F$ such as $\log$?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: The first term of the series is undefined.

Comment: That's right. Let me fix the series. I meant to start the sum at 1.

Comment: @StratosFair That hint doesn't help, as Patrick's comment shows.

Comment: Now, you could fix the question.

Comment: @jjagmath right, my bad. I wrote too quickly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a convergent $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum\sqrt{a_n/n}$ diverges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $a_n = \frac{1}{n \ln(n)^2}$. This is undefined for $n=0$ and $n=1$, so just choose $a_0 = a_1 = 0$ and use the formula for $n \ge 2$.

$\sum_n a_n$ converges by the [Integral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). We have $$\int_2^\infty \frac 1 {x \ln(x)^2} dx = -\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \Bigg|_2^{\infty} = -\left(0 -  \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\right) = \frac{1}{\ln(2)} < \infty$$
so we have convergence.

On the other hand, $\sqrt{\frac{a_n}{n}} = \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ and this one *diverges* by the same Integral Test:
$$\int_2^\infty \frac 1 {x \ln(x)} dx = \ln(\ln(x)) \Bigg|_2^{\infty}$$ but $\ln(\ln(x)) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: This is clever. Thank you!